# Creating a geographic file for use with tmap and coming up with error when coding shapefile

Tags: r, shapefile, tmap, cartography

I am trying to reproduce a map I found here: http://zevross.com/blog/2018/10/02/creating-beautiful-demographic-maps-in-r-with-the-tidycensus-and-tmap-packages/

I am using RStudio and am running the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)      # For plotting
library(tidycensus)   # For downloading Census data
library(tmap)         # For creating tmap
library(tmaptools)    # For reading and processing spatial data related to tmap
library(dplyr)        # For data wrangling
library(sf)           # For reading, writing and working with spatial objects

census_api_key("enter your API key here", overwrite = TRUE)

dat12 <- get_acs("county", table = "B27001", year = 2012, 
                 output = "tidy", state = NULL, geometry = FALSE) %>%
  rename(`2012` = estimate) %>%
  select(-NAME, -moe) 

dat16 <- get_acs("county", table = "B27001", year = 2016, 
                 output = "tidy", state = NULL, geometry = TRUE, shift_geo = TRUE) %>%
  rename(`2016` = estimate) %>%
  select(-moe)

dat <- left_join(dat16, dat12, by = c("GEOID", "variable"))
st_geometry(dat) <- NULL # This drops the geometry and leaves a table

head(dat)

dat <- mutate(dat,
              cat = case_when(
                variable %in% paste0("B27001_0",
                                     c("09","12","37","40")) ~ "pop1834",
                variable %in% paste0("B27001_0",
                                     c("11","14","39","42")) ~ "pop1834ni")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(cat))

# Create long version
dat <- tidyr::gather(dat, year, estimate, c(`2012`, `2016`))

# Group the data by our new categories and sum
dat <- group_by(dat, GEOID, NAME, year, cat) %>%
  summarize(estimate = sum(estimate)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  tidyr::spread(cat, estimate) 

dat <- mutate(dat, est = (pop1834ni/pop1834) * 100) %>%
  select(-c(pop1834, pop1834ni)) %>%
  tidyr::spread(year, est) %>%
  mutate(diff = `2016`-`2012`)

head(dat)

datlong <- select(dat, -diff) %>%
  tidyr::gather(year, estimate, c(`2012`, `2016`)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(med = round(median(estimate, na.rm = TRUE), 1))

ggplot(datlong, aes(estimate)) +
  geom_histogram(fill = "firebrick2", 
                 color = "white", bins = 60) +
  xlab("Uninsured adults ages 18-34 by county (%)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  facet_wrap(~year, ncol = 1) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = med,
                 group = year), lty = "dashed") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("Median = ", med), x = med, y = 55))

d10 <- top_n(dat, 10, diff) %>%
  mutate(type = "Insured population decreased",
         difftemp = diff)

i10 <- top_n(dat, -10, diff) %>%
  mutate(type = "Insured population increased",
         difftemp = abs(diff))

id10 <- bind_rows(list(i10, d10)) %>%
  arrange(desc(difftemp))

ggplot(id10) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = forcats::fct_reorder(NAME, difftemp), 
               y = difftemp, fill = type)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("firebrick2", "cyan4")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank()) +
  ggtitle("Counties with the greatest change (+/-) in
    insured population, ages 18-34, 2012-2016") +
  ylab("Difference in % insured (2016 - 2012)") +
  xlab("")

shp <- dat16 %>%
  filter(variable == "B27001_001") # much faster than using distinct()
select(GEOID, NAME) %>%
  left_join(dat, by = c("GEOID", "NAME")) %>%
  arrange(GEOID) %>%
  rename(uninsured_2012 = `2012`,
         uninsured_2016 = `2016`,
         uninsured_diff = diff)
```

Up until the last bit of code, the one that begins with shp, everything runs perfect. Once,

```
shp <- dat16 %>%
  filter(variable == "B27001_001") # much faster than using distinct()
select(GEOID, NAME) %>%
  left_join(dat, by = c("GEOID", "NAME")) %>%
  arrange(GEOID) %>%
  rename(uninsured_2012 = `2012`,
         uninsured_2016 = `2016`,
         uninsured_diff = diff)
```

is run, I get the following error:

```
Error in select(GEOID, NAME) : object 'GEOID' not found
```

I have checked dat16 and dat. GEOID and NAME are present there. I am not sure what is wrong with the SELECT function as I have not loaded another library which may interfere with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I see now what was missing, a %>% (pipe) following the 'filter':

```
shp <- dat16 %>%
  filter(variable == "B27001_001") %>% # much faster than using distinct()
  select(GEOID, NAME) %>%
  left_join(dat, by = c("GEOID", "NAME")) %>%
  arrange(GEOID) %>%
  rename(
    uninsured_2012 = `2012`,
    uninsured_2016 = `2016`,
    uninsured_diff = diff
  )
```